# CSV load data infile lead to a triple size database CSV

Tags: php, mysql, file-io, load, size

I have four csv files and all of them have a size of 200 gb. I'm trying to load these four files as separated tables of a database. The problem comes with one specific file (100gb) when I use load data infile the size of that specific database becomes 250GB I'm aware that using MYISAM storing engine will lead me to this, however I'm using INNODB and even using INNODB leads me to a file of 204GB below are my current my.cnf config and php.ini config I think I'm sure I have messed something.

```
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all MySQL clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# especially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer_size     = 1G
max_allowed_packet  = 512M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 128M
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_open_cache       = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 8M
query_cache_size        = 128M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#slow_query_log     = 1
#slow_query_log_file    = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size   = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem
secure_file_priv=""
innodb_doublewrite = 0
innodb_support_xa = 0
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 10G
innodb_log_file_size = 512M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
```

and here is php.ini file

```
https://gist.github.com/PhenomAmd/9e5940ee62bd12fa5d25609d93d2119e
```

weirdest thing is I remove all files and I just leave this 100gb file still leads me to a 280GB database the vps has 16GB ram and 400GB SSD I know that data will fit the server as I have did it in the past lastly the command I'm using is this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/trade.csv' 
INTO TABLE trade 
CHARACTER SET latin1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY "'" 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 4 LINES (fid,serial_num,file_since_dt,bureau_id,member_kob,member_code,member_short_name,member_area_code,member_phone_num,acct_num,account_status,owner_indic,posted_dt,pref_cust_code,acct_type,contract_type,terms_num_paymts,terms_frequency,terms_amt,opened_dt,last_paymt_dt,last_purchased_dt,closed_dt,reporting_dt,reporting_mode,paid_off_dt,collateral,currency_code,high_credit_amt,cur_balance_amt,credit_limit,amt_past_due,paymt_pat_hst,paymt_pat_str_dt,paymt_pat_end_dt,cur_mop_status,remarks_code,restruct_dt,suppress_set_dt,suppress_expir_dt,max_delinqncy_amt,max_delinqncy_dt,max_delinqncy_mop,num_paymts_late,num_months_review,num_paymts_30_day,num_paymts_60_day,num_paymts_90_day,num_paymts_120_day,appraise_value,first_no_payment_dt,saldo_insoluto,last_paymt_amt,crc_indic,plazo_meses,monto_credito_original,last_past_due_dt,interest_amt,cur_interest_mop,days_past_due,email);
```

SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM database_name

```
+-------+--------+---------+------------+-----------+----------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Name  | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows      | Avg_row_length | Data_length  | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time | Check_time | Collation         | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
+-------+--------+---------+------------+-----------+----------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| trade | InnoDB |      10 | Dynamic    | 210002438 |            509 | 107098406912 |               0 |            0 |   7340032 |           NULL | 2021-07-02 11:11:47 | NULL        | NULL       | latin1_general_ci |     NULL |                |         |
+-------+--------+---------+------------+-----------+----------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

show processlist shows 3 times same query I don't know why either:

```
+-----+------------+-----------+---------+---------+------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id  | User       | Host      | db      | Command | Time | State        | Info                                                                                                 |
+-----+------------+-----------+---------+---------+------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 112 | phpmyadmin | localhost | NULL    | Sleep   | 4810 |              | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 113 | root       | localhost | buronal | Query   | 4810 | executing    | LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/trade.csv'
INTO TABLE trade
CHARACTER SET latin1
FIELDS  |
| 182 | phpmyadmin | localhost | NULL    | Sleep   | 4128 |              | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 183 | root       | localhost | buronal | Query   | 4128 | executing    | LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/trade.csv'
INTO TABLE trade
CHARACTER SET latin1
FIELDS  |
| 250 | phpmyadmin | localhost | NULL    | Sleep   | 3446 |              | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 251 | root       | localhost | buronal | Query   | 3446 | executing    | LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/trade.csv'
INTO TABLE trade
CHARACTER SET latin1
FIELDS  |
| 484 | phpmyadmin | localhost | NULL    | Sleep   |  755 |              | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 485 | root       | localhost | buronal | Query   |  755 | Sending data | SELECT * FROM `trade` LIMIT 0, 25                                                                    |
| 526 | root       | localhost | NULL    | Query   |    0 | starting     | show processlist                                                                                     |
| 551 | phpmyadmin | localhost | NULL    | Sleep   |   73 |              | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 552 | root       | localhost | buronal | Query   |   73 | Sending data | SELECT * FROM `trade` LIMIT 0, 25                                                                    |
+-----+------------+-----------+---------+---------+------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Can you please share output of SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM database_name

Comment: first post updated @Varun thanks im reinserting the data to see if this time i can get that base done, seems like it will go up for a lot of data again :(

Comment: Sounds like you have `BIGINTs` for columns that hold small numbers.  "1,2,3,4" in csv averages 2 bytes per number; Bigint is always 8 bytes + overhead.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can diagnose further.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like

- `BIGINTs` for columns that hold small numbers:  "1,2,3,4" in csv averages 2 bytes per number; Bigint is always 8 bytes + overhead.
- `CHAR` vs `VARCHAR` is another potential problem.  `CHAR(255)` takes 255 bytes when latin1; `VARCHAR(255)` takes only the space needed.  Also, InnoDB handles `CHAR` differently than MyISAM.
- over-sized `DECIMAL`
- `DOUBLE` vs `FLOAT`
- `INT` for a boolean flag
- and maybe others
- The "overhead" in InnoDB is usually significantly more than in MyISAM (contrary to your first comparison).

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can diagnose further.

Your `my.cnf` looks tight for 16GB if you are using *both* MyISAM and InnoDB.  Cut these in half:  'key_buffer_size' and 'innodb_buffer_pool_size'.

After you realize that you should go with only InnoDB:  'key_buffer_size=50M' and 'innodb_buffer_pool_size=10G'

Comment: actually all my problem was related to something so dumb and silly it actually pisses me off, i forgot to tell that all my load data infile where made from phpmyadmin so the size it was because everytime the connection timed out it restarts again and since it didnt had any uniqueness or indexed i  was getting like 438M rows duplicated i started using mysql cli 100% and all my problems went away

Comment: i appreciate your guidance i have picked your reply but i need 15 rep to cast a vote @rick james

Comment: ill do it and cast my vote thanks for the advice